# Local variable and Block usage

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, block

I wrote code that executes a function it receives from the (future) client, in a loop with some parameters. will call it func(name it).

Inside the function the client usually generate expression in the same variables(by GetUncertainty - each variable must be cleared before use). To do so , the simple idea is to use Block. Later , a code is executed that handles di and i outside the function.So, di and i must be globals(there could be more, it is flexible).

BTW, I know it is not efficient, but efficiency is not an issue.

```
func[v_, a_, r_] := 
(V = v; A = a; R = r; 
 Block[{V, A, R},i = V A + A 10 + R 100; di = GetUncertainty[i, {V, A, R}];] ;
 Print[di])
```

The problem is that the client must reset the vars by hand. That means that the function parameters can't be V_,A_,R_ , otherwise The vars in the block will be replace by the values. I didn't manage to overcome this in any other way.

Another question in a similar issue. if I have 
vars = {V,A,R,DR} , then
Block[vars , ..code.. ] , throws error that it is not a list.whereas Block[ {V,A,R,DR},..code..] works. How to overcome this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your application what you need are Formal Symbols.  These are a set of Symbols with the Attribute `Protected` so that they cannot accidentally be assigned a value.  They may be entered with e.g. <kbd>Esc</kbd>`$A`<kbd>Esc</kbd> for Formal Capital A.  You can then use `ReplaceAll` (short form `/.`) as george showed to substitute your desired values.

Your code would be something like this:

```
func[v_, a_, r_] :=
  Module[{i, di},
    i = \[FormalCapitalV] \[FormalCapitalA] + \[FormalCapitalA] 10 + \[FormalCapitalR] 100;
    di = GetUncertainty[i, {\[FormalCapitalV], \[FormalCapitalA], \[FormalCapitalR]}];
    di /. {\[FormalCapitalV] -> v, \[FormalCapitalA] -> a, \[FormalCapitalR] -> r}
  ]
```

That looks horrible here but in a Notebook it looks like this:

[image]

I included `Module` to show how you should properly localize utility Symbols such as `i` and `di` but this particuarly simple function could also be written without them:

[image]

Your second question regarding "`vars = {V,A,R,DR}` then `Block[vars , ..code.. ]`" is answered here: [How to set Block local variables by code?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19758/121)

---

Dedicated StackExchange site:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

its hard to unravel what you are trying to do, but the best approach may be to simply never assign values to symbols that need to be used as pure symbols in some context. Then you don't even need the Block[].

```
func[v_, a_, r_] := (
    i = V A + A 10 + R 100; 
    di = GetUncertainty[i, {V, A, R}];
    Print[di /. {V->v,A->a,R->r])
```

starting your own symbol names with Caps is frowned upon by the way as you risk conflict with built in symbols.

Note also there is a dedicated site mathematica.stackexchange.com